# Probability of getting at least one ball of each color

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given that we have an urn containing $N=\sum{N_i}$ balls, $N_1$ of color $1$, $N_2$ of color $2, \dots, N_k$ of color $k$, we draw $m$ balls from the urn such that $m \geq k$ and $m \leq \max(N - N_i)$ what is the probability that we get at least one ball of each color? 
I just cant find a reasonable way to express this condition in order to get a closed form formula for it.

Comment: You can get a formula from inclusion-exclusion. Haven't tried simplifying it yet so I don't know how hard it is to get it into closed form.

Comment: That's the thing I tried getting that in closed form, but didn't successeded. I haven't done binomials for a while now and I'm aware there are quite a lot of tricks with thouse so was wondering if there is some magic to get it in closed.